# Proper use of phantomJS with proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

**Hello to all**

I use selenium with phantomJS driver, with all clients that have internet connection without proxy server, the program works fine

In case of user that have proxy server the program works (without setting proxy settings)
but:

- sometimes the program can not start (phantomJS timeout exception).
- sometimes the program start but works slowly.
- sometimes the program start and crush in the middle.

My question is what is the proper use of pahntomJS when i have proxy server
should i init PhantomJS service, PhantomJS options and so on...

**Things i tried:**

- set proxy address and port.

but the result is still the same

i understand that the proxy didn't have username and password otherwise it shouldn't enter the website in the first place.

**My phantomJS init code:**

```
private static IWebDriver driver;
private static PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
private static PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();

service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;    
service.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy={0}:{1}", proxyAddress, proxyPort)); // the way i tried to init proxy address

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(webSiteUrl);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

- should i add more options, services, or add arguments to work with proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in this matter, e.g. see PhantomJS issues:
[#12420](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12420) or [#11619](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11619).

At first glance your approach looks correct (you provided proxy and its type will be set to `http` [by default](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html)). Nevertheless as noted by [Selenium-related source](https://github.com/jimevans/WebDriverProxyExamples/blob/80a99dc181a663b90a1b04deafe5ee793d0e0b52/WebDriverProxyUtilities/WebDriverFactory.cs), try alternative setup shown there, i.e.

```
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.ProxyType = "http";
service.Proxy = "host:port";
```

If it is still not enough, try to provide desired capabilities:

```
var options = new PhantomJSOptions();                        
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"proxyType", "manual"},
    {"httpProxy", "host:port"}
});
```

These are just random suggestions, try them at least, and kindly share what have worked for you, if any (I'm referring to PhantomJS 2.0.0 and Selenium.WebDriver 2.48.2).